# BigTable: One large query or a dozen small queries?

Tags: go, bigtable, google-cloud-bigtable

I store series of `event`s in BigTable with the form of:

```
rowKey                | col_1 | col_2
----------------------|-------|------
uuid1!uuid2!timestamp | val1  | val2
....
```

`col_1` holds a `float64` and `col_2` holds a string 63 characters long.

Specific ranges within this series of `event`s are grouped and are loosely associated to an object we'll call an `operation`:

```
{
    "id": 123,
    "startDate": "2019-07-15T14:02:12.335+02:00",
    "endDate": "2019-07-15T14:02:16.335+02:00"
}
```

So you may say that an `operation` is a timewindow of `event`s, and may be associated to 10-1000 `event`s.

When I want to display this data to the user, I first query the `operation` objects, and then I execute a BigTable query for each `operation` to find the `event`s it covers.

Through monitoring I've discovered that each BigTable (a development instance, mind you) query may take between 20ms to 300ms.

This got me wondering, given BigTable's architecture - does it make sense to execute small, individual queries?

Does it make more sense to execute one big query that covers my range of `operation`s, then divide the events to their respective `operation`s in my application?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but rowkey=timestamp is a notorious antipattern: https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/schema-design-time-series#ensure_that_your_row_key_avoids_hotspotting

Comment: Yes you're right, it was simplified for the sake of example. I'll edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely yes, but the details matter here.

If there are only a few operations per user request then it may actually be better to issue the small queries in parallel. This will get you the best possible latency per request, at the expense of some per-request CPU overhead for your cluster. Your application code will also be more complicated.

If there are lots of operations per user request, you'll definitely want the increased throughput efficiency that you get from scanning.

For an advanced use case you could also compromise between the two and break the scan into N shards which you run in parallel, where N << #operations.

The one thing you definitely shouldn't do is send the small requests one at a time, as you'll just produce a bunch of unnecessary round trips!

Comment: Great and clear answer, are there any ballpark figures for `If there are lots of operations per user request` ?

Comment: It depends a bit on how strict your latency requirements are. I'd start by seeing if you're alright with the performance you get from a single scan, since that's the simplest approach. But a decent rule of thumb would be that diminishing returns will set in beyond 10ish parallel requests, as tail latency will quickly become dominated by the slowest one.